# Line Break in OBIEE 11g

Tags: business-objects, obiee

I am a creating a report using OBIEE 11g and need to figure out the line break. For example, I have the following variables: Account Name, Address, City, State etc...I want to be able to have all these variables in one column but on different lines.

For e.g:
Account Name 
Address 
City 
State

The following code works with Business Object but not OBIEE 11g. I need to recreate the same thing in Obiee 11g.

```
=[Account Name]+Char(10)+[Account Address 1]+Char(10) +[Account City]+", " +[Account State]+"  "+  [Account Postal Code]  +Char(10)+[Region]+Char(10)+Char(10)+Char(10)+[Current Site Status]+" - "+[Number of Enrollments (per CTMS)]+Char(10)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: And OBIEE "analysis" or a BI Publisher "report"? The objects are totally different as they come from 2 different technologies. Most people use them interchangeably which is the first error to make.

Comment: I am working with OBIEE "Analysis". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you "variables" are "columns". "variables" are variables in a programmatic sense.

If you want columns vertically aligned on top of each other, then you can simply put them in to the "columns" section of a pivot table view for your analysis.